# Error: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is the code part:

```
import discord 
import random from discord.utils 
import get import time

 class MyClient(discord.Client):
     #Einloggen
     async def on_ready(self):
         print("Eingeloggt")
 
     #Wenn Nachricht gepostet wird
     async def on_message(self, message):
         if message.author == client.user:
             return
        
         if message.content == "$help":
            print("help")
 
         if message.content.startswith("$play"):
             where = message.content.split(" ")[1]
             channel = get(message.guild.channels, name=where)
             voicechannel = await channel.connect()
             voicechannel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('triggered.mp3'))


client = MyClient()
client.run("")
```

This is the Error:

```
line 22, in on_message
voicechannel = await channel.connect()
AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'connect
```

I've installed discord, opus, ffmpg, and a couple other things what should I do?
please help

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you're trying to connect to a text channel, you only can to voice channels. Instead of:

```py
channel = get(message.guild.channels, name=where)
```

Use the `Guild.voice_channels` attribute

```py
channel = get(message.guild.voice_channels, name=where)
```

Comment: Now there is another error:    raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.                                                                              If I type "pip install ffmpeg" it says that ffmpeg allready exists

Comment: That's not an error related with your issue here,

Comment: Could you please help me anyways?

Comment: I could, but I don't know much about discord.py voice, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284892/discord-bot-python-discord-errors-clientexception-ffmpeg-was-not-found) question